# How to add URL prefix to js and css imports in index.html with webpack?

Tags: webpack, html-webpack-plugin

I am serving my compiled app with Tomcat. The app is not served from the root context but with a suffix - e.g. `mysite.com/myapp`.

I need webpack to add this `myapp` prefix to the `js` and `css` imports in `index.html`.

I need this:

```html
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/myapp/favicon.ico">
  <link href="/myapp/app.9c885d75239355add0ca8f22362e289c.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="root"></div>
  <script src="/myapp/vendor.1c28bcf2a2efacc7d62d.js"></script>
  <script src="/myapp/app.d678b996583f01bd2f7d.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

But right now I have this:

```html
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link href="app.9c885d75239355add0ca8f22362e289c.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="root"></div>
  <script src="vendor.1c28bcf2a2efacc7d62d.js"></script>
  <script src="app.d678b996583f01bd2f7d.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

A hacky way would be to run a script during the build to change the links but I would like to have a more proper webpack solution.

I'm using `HtmlWebpackPlugin` and [React Redux Starter Kit](https://github.com/davezuko/react-redux-starter-kit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set

```
output: {
  filename: '/myapp/[name].[chunkhash].js',
  ...
},
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess we can also use [Webpack publicPath](https://webpack.js.org/guides/public-path/)

```js
output: {
  publicPath: '/myapp/',
  ...
},
```